# NativeDragEvent Not Working?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, drag-and-drop, flash-cs5

I have a project in Flash Professional CS5 and ActionScript 3.

I have various objects that I can drag around the screen (tile1-tile5, and drop them on any of five different places (slot1-slot5). This works without the slightest bit of issue. All of this code is placed on the first keyframe for tile1-tile5.

However, I need to use the NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_ENTER and NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_EXIT. My code is below. It is placed on the first keyframe for slot1 in this example.

```
slot1.addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_OVER, slot1enter);
slot1.addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_EXIT, slot1exit);

function slot1enter(evt:NativeDragEvent):void {
    trace("Drag entered.");
}

function slot1exit(evt:NativeDragEvent):void{
    trace("Drag exit.");
}
```

What is going on here? How can I get this to work?

Comment: It works for me, so it looks like you'll have to elaborate some more.  What are the slots? Where are they defined?  Presumably, they're MovieClips since you're working in Flash Pro, but it wouldn't hurt to state that explicitly.  Also, have you tried defining a Slot class and adding the event listeners in there?  I mean, that's what you should ultimately end up doing anyway; although, I'm not saying that's the solution, since it should also work how you currently have it.

Comment: I may just need to drop this method altogether, as I realized I need this to work both in and out of Air. Sigh. Thanks, tho.

Comment: Too bad.  As a side note, the implementation of the InteractiveObject in **Flex** does include a non-AIR DragEvent.  Of course, that would mean using the Flex SDK, which means additional load time, added complexity to your project, etc..  Anyway, just throwing it out there as another alternative, even though it's probably not something you'd consider if you're already well into a project.  Best of luck.

Comment: @Downvoter...why? I can't imagine this being "not useful", especially for beginning and intermediate level programmers. An explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a confusion here. I'm using the built-in startDrag in Flash to drag an interactive element. However, NativeDragEnter and NativeDragExit only work with OS drags, so this is apples and oranges. One won't work with the other.

Answer (score 1):

NativeDragEvent is only available for AIR runtime.

Assure your Flash Pro publish is targeting the AIR runtime.